# Why can't I install a library with a minus sign in it?

Tags: events, import, python-import

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to import a module that I installed, "python-evtx".  I successfully installed it, but when I try to import it in the environment (Python 3.10.9) using Idle I get a syntax error that points at the "-" sign. As far as I can tell, import chokes on that"-" sign.  Can anybody help?  Thanks!

Here is a screenshot of my issue:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9oxj.png)

Comment: Does `import Evtx` work? The install name might not match the import name (If so, send a PR to update their docs)

Comment: Unfortunately, neither combo works. See below:

Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import python-evtx
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import python-evtx
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import evtx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'evtx'
>>>

https://chapinb.com/python-forensics-handbook/ch03_event_logs.html